# (Tampermonkey) Elements Not Changing

Tags: tampermonkey

I'm fairly new to JS, so bear with me. I'm trying to change a website into dark mode via tampermonkey. I'm using the traditional "if color = #fff change to #whatever" on a 1000ms loop. Some elements don't change, though their color is #fff (I checked) I tried to change their color manually by doing

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName(class);
x[0].style.backgroundColor == "#303030";
```

No such luck. I tried the !important modifier and a plethora of small changes, nothing. I logged the element and it's current color. It has the right element, and the color is just a blank comment. There aren't any error messages to go by either. Just to be sure, I changed the color manually and it worked. Does anyone know what the hell is wrong? I've been at this for hours and it's frustrating.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `==` is a comparison, not an assignment. You have to use a single `=` sign here.

Comment: I used '=' as well.

Comment: @Memedustry Without more info, I can't really help. Can you maybe make some example HTML where you could show what doesn't work? Or at least share what you tried? You just gave two lines of code, I am sure you wrote more. Maybe if you try to isolate the problem, you'll even find a solution - happens to me 50% of the time.